# PIVOTing BigQuery tables on DATE type

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to pivot a table with each row being a transaction with a date. E.g.

```sql
WITH Produce AS (
  SELECT 'Kale' as product, 51 as sales, DATE('2020-01-01') as dates UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 23, DATE('2020-01-02') UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 45, DATE('2020-01-03') UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 3,  DATE('2020-01-04') UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 70, DATE('2020-01-01') UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 85, DATE('2020-01-02') UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 77, DATE('2020-01-03') UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 1, DATE('2020-01-04')
)
```

My query is something like this.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Produce
PIVOT(sum(sales) FOR dates IN (DATE('2020-01-01'), DATE('2020-01-02'), DATE('2020-01-03'), DATE('2020-01-04')))
```

However BigQuery returns the following error.

```
Generating an implicit alias for this PIVOT value is not supported; please provide an explicit alias at [14:41]
```

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#rules_pivot_column), pivot columns with type of date should be able to generate alias implicitly, or is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Rules for pivot_column:](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator)

> A pivot_column must be a constant.

`DATE('2020-01-01')` is an expression, not a constant. So you need to use one of followings.

```sql
PIVOT(sum(sales) FOR dates IN (DATE '2020-01-01', ...) -- explicit DATE literal
-- or
PIVOT(sum(sales) FOR dates IN ('2020-01-01', ...) -- literal implicitly coerced to DATE type
-- or
PIVOT(sum(sales) FOR dates IN (DATE('2020-01-01') AS _2020_01_01, ...) -- alias
```

###### Dynamic SQL Example

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * FROM Produce
   PIVOT (SUM(sales) FOR dates IN (%s))
""", TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', '2020-01-4')), '[]'));
```

[image]

- [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate)

Comment: I see. If I'm using `UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', '2020-01-4'))` how could I convert the array of dates to said format? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @birdx0810, In that case, you need to use a **dynamic sql**, kindly check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use below instead

```
SELECT * FROM Produce
PIVOT(sum(sales) FOR dates IN ('2020-01-01','2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'))
```

with output

[image]